# Dynamic textview to be visible on opening the app again

Tags: android, textview

I am trying to add a dynamic textview to the page when I click OK in the dialog box. My problem is that I want that textview to be visible even when the app is opened again. 
P.S. I can add multiple textviews(1 at a time) and all should be visible on opening app again. Example : Creating a new Playlist and the new playlist name appears always . Can anyone guide me how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store info about added TextView-s in SharedPreferences and when app is opened again get this info from SharedPreferences by getStringSet for example (to get added TextView's key names) and by other methods and create new TextView-s and add them to an activity layout.

ADDITION:

The most universal approach to this task is to save JSONArray which contains TextView-s data in SharedPreferences as a string by using toString() method and when app is opened again read JSONArray from SharedPreferences as a string and fill data of newly created TextView-s.

EXAMPLE:

```
private JSONArray data;    

...    

SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences("application", 0);
data = new JSONArray( pref.getString("text_views_data", null) );

List<TextView> tvList = new ArrayList<TextView>();
for (int i = 0; i < data.length(); i++){
   JSONObject ob = data.get(i);        

   TextView tv = new TextView(this);
   tv.setText( ob.getString("text") );
   tvList.add(tv);
}

...

private saveTextViewData(TextView tv){
    JSONObject ob = new JSONObject();
    ob.put("text", tv.getText());
    data.put(ob);

    SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("application", 0);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
    editor.putString("text_views_data", data.toString() );
    editor.commit();
}
```

You should call saveTextViewData method when you add new TextView.

Answer (score 0):

you can store each the TextView as an object in an array of objects. Then you can save this array in a `SharedPreferences` then when you open the application get the array from `SharedPreferences` and add the TextViews to the application dynamically.
This is a simple solution!